# Facebook photo opengraph

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-opengraph, photo

![enter image description here][1]

test img link = http://www.kimjongchan.com/2012/10/19/test/

anyone knows how to remove the link?

I want to remove "photo" link because pudding camera does't have any landing page. It's just photo taking app not sharing app.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because that is object given for action , without object or action we can't do opengraph related things

Answer (score 0):

Every Open Graph object has to have a publicly accessible URL.
You could choose to not show the photo when somebody visits that URL though, but I don't see the point.
You are **sharing** the photo on Facebook, but you don't want to **share** the photo on your website?

Perhaps you should use [regular photo uploading](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) instead of Open Graph.